# A separate UIViewController for UITextField - iOS

Tags: architecture, mvc, ios, mobile, apple

[image]

In my iOS project I have a set of custom textfields, e.g. for password entry.

As an example, such textfields can contain additional views and logic - for example, show or hide a password with a press of a button.

Since this logic is not used anywhere outside the textField, I have an idea to create a *PasswordTextFieldController* and set the textField as its only *view*.

The show/hide password behavior goes to the *PasswordTextFieldController* and the controller itself is used as a child view controller with the help of [View Controller Containment](https://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/containment-view-controller/).

As all the relevant logic has been encapsulated, I could reuse the same *PasswordTextFieldController* during both signup and login.

Are there any drawbacks in this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of heavy for just one text field in my opinion but it is an option. I think the most common way to do something like this is to make a subclass of UITextField that tracks the extra functionality itself. Even that might be too heavy and it makes composing functionality difficult. I recommend instead that you make your own "PasswordController" class that doesn't derive from UIViewController and has a reference to the text field.

That said, here is an article from someone I respect as a developer who at least entertains the idea: [Many Controllers Make Light Work](http://khanlou.com/2016/02/many-controllers/).

Comment: Thank for your comment. Indeed, it doesn't make any difference if I use a `PasswordController` derived from `NSObject` or an `UIViewController`. For example, a simple object could also be reused in the UICollectionView. But the idea is good and works well for me.